# Passing a collection from a router to a view

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

It's throwing this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fetch' of undefined* in the view. @collection is undefined in the view, despite seemingly passing it in through the router.

If you're curious, the ajaxSubmit is being used to handle a file upload.

Any ideas?

**routers/tracks.js.coffee**

```
...
initialize: ->
  @collection = new Jambox.Collections.Tracks()
  @collection.fetch() # works!

new: (name) ->
  view = new Jambox.Views.TracksNew(name, collection: @collection)
```

**views/tracks/new.js.coffee**

```
events:
  'click #submit': 'uploadTrack'

uploadTrack: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(@el).find('#new-track').ajaxSubmit(
    success: => @collection.fetch()  # Uncaught TypeError
  )
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This is why it wasn't passing the collection through to the view.

**Originally:**

```
new: (name) ->
  view = new Jambox.Views.TracksNew(name, collection: @collection)
```

**The fix:**

```
new: (name) ->
  view = new Jambox.Views.TracksNew(name: name, collection: @collection)
```

Answer (score 1):

The context (AKA `@` or `this`) for the `success` callback probably isn't your view object, it is probably the same context used for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and that is:

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`)

You should bind your success callback to the view with a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

```
uploadTrack: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(@el).find('#new-track').ajaxSubmit(
    success: => @collection.fetch()
  )
  ...
```

Comment: That was definitely an issue. Good eye! I'm still getting the same error, though. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What's calling `uploadTrack`? Do you need to fat-arrow that as well or provide an explicit context for an `on` call?

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out it was the format of the hash I was passing into the view. Thanks for your help, mu.